# file include not working on heroku server (No such file or directory)

Tags: php, heroku, path

Php line is working fine on localhost but not on live heroku server, even if I have the same file and folder structure.

```
require(APPPATH . '../../vendor/mpdf/mpdf/mpdf.php');
```

I am getting following error on heroku live server is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'application/../../vendor/mpdf/mpdf/mpdf.php' (include_path='.:/app/.heroku/php/lib/php') in /app/CI/application/libraries/PDFLib.php on line 5
```

spend a lot of time trying to figure out what could be the reasons behind this, any help will appreciated.

Comment: Are you using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/)?

Comment: Yes I'm using composer and I have found solution of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran **composer update** with my branch. It ends up updating the `composer.lock` file and adding the “mpd/mpdf” and “setasign/fpdi” packages

So what is happening is, my `composer.lock` file doesn’t include mpdf or fpdi. When Heroku tries to build the application, it modifies the “vendor” directory to match what my `composer.lock` file specifies.

And my `composer.lock` file specifies that mpdf and fpdi should not be part of the application

However, this is different from the `composer.json` file, which specifies that mpdf and fpdi should be part of the application.

Comment: [`composer.lock` should be kept up to date with `composer.json` and both files should be committed to version control](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file).